# Grothendieck topology and relation with usual topologies

Tags: category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Recently I stumbled upon the definition of $\textbf{Grothendieck}$ $\textbf{topologies}$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$. I do know that is one of the most interesting parts of the contemporary algebraic approach for topology and geometry as well. Though, I was curious to understand the aim of this particular name and the correlation with the usual notion of the topology on a usual set; if for instance is a generalization or the usual topology is a kind of a special restriction of the former definition. Although I did find some interesting articles about it (for instance https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/historical+note+on+Grothendieck+topology) I didn't understand exactly.

So, can we recover the usual definition of a topology on a set $X$ from the definition of a $\textbf{Grothendieck}$ $\textbf{topologies}$ on a specific category $\mathcal{C}$? If not, what can we define through that definition with an analogue in the usual point-set topology?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology) is actually pretty good. Here's a super-quick summary, though:

- To a topological space $X$, we can associate a category $Open(X)$ whose objects are the open sets of $X$, and whose morphisms are the inclusion maps (this is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology#Motivation)). While in general $X$ cannot be recovered from $Open(X)$ (think about indiscrete topological spaces), if $X$ is *sober* then it can be; and the vast majority of naturally-occurring topological spaces are sober. So, for most intents and purposes you can conflate $X$ with $Open(X)$.
- A sheaf on $X$ is then a contravariant functor from $Open(X)$ satisfying some properties - specifically, *locality* and *gluing*. The one you want to focus on here is the *gluing* property, for which we need the notion of a family of open sets **covering** another open set.
- A Grothendieck topology is basically what you get when you ask for a category which behaves like the category of open sets in the sense that it has a good notion of covering. What do I mean by this? Well, given a category $C$, we want to think of elements of $C$ as being open sets in some imaginary topological space $X_C$ (which might not, in fact, exist); the Grothendieck topology just tells us when some family of "opens" covers some other "open".
- What exactly does this mean? Well, a first guess would be that we want a set $\mathcal{S}$ of pairs $(a, M)$ where $a$ is an object of $C$ and $M$ is a family of morphisms with codomain $a$ (where $(a, M)\in\mathcal{S}$ should mean "$M$ covers $a$"). It turns out that this isn't quite right, and what we actually want is more complicated - this is the notion of a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology#Sieves).
- So basically, a site (= a category with a Grothendieck topology) is a context for sheaf theory. Note that while every topological space yields a site, there are some sites which do not come from any space (see ???). The definition of a sheaf on a site is slightly complicated, but the wikipedia page does a decent job of explaining it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology#Sites_and_sheaves).
- Why would you want a notion of sheaf theory for objects more general than topological spaces? Well, the original motivation (to my understanding) was to develop a notion of etale cohomology for *schemes*; so if you care about schemes, you should care about sites. Since then, I know that Grothendieck topologies have also been used to give a categorial interpretation of [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) (see e.g. Maclane and Moerdijk's book, "Sheaves in geometry and logic").

Comment: Thank you for your answer Noah! Good job! Just a quick question. So we cannot recover the usual definition of a topology from the Grothendieck's Topology defintion right? What is common though is the idea of coverings right?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I'm not sure I understand your first question. What do you mean by "recover the usual definition of a topology from the Grothendieck's Topology definition"? It is not the case, for example, that every Grothendieck topology is equivalent to the Grothendieck topology corresponding to some actual topological space; does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I mean that the usual definition of a topology (a subset of the power set with some special properties like finite intersections and infinite unions etc..) is not a "special" case of the definition of Grothendieck topology? For instance if there is any specific category associated to a set $X$ such that the Grothendieck topology on it, gives a topology on the set $X$ in the usual way.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Look at my first bullet point - if $X$ is a topological space, then there's a canonical Grothendieck topology on $Open(X)$, and $X$ can be recovered from this assuming $X$ is sober. I think this is the most along these lines that can be said.